# Clicking a button on a DataGridView Cell Button triggers all the cell button commands in the row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 9 columns. Column index 4 and 8 are Cell Buttons. When I click on button index 4 it will execute the command given but will also execute the command given for button index 8. Either way which ever button I click (4 or 8) it will always execute ACTION 1 then ACTION 2

```
private void dgvItems_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[4] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewRow)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("ACTION 1: Column index is " + e.ColumnIndex + "; Row Index " + e.RowIndex);
    }

    if (senderGrid.Columns[8] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewRow)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("ACTION 2: Column index is " + e.ColumnIndex + "; Row Index " + e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: No wonder ... Both of your conditions are true, it will always display both messageboxes. Try solution given by @Eric below.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check current column by `e.ColumnIndex`. Correct the `if` condition as:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
    MessageBox.Show("ACTION 1: Column index is " + e.ColumnIndex + "; Row Index " + e.RowIndex);

if (e.ColumnIndex == 8)
....
```